# Use "5 days ago (Tue)" if within the last week in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment.js.

The default for relative past days is `"5 days ago"`. But what I want is that if it's within a week ago it should return `"5 days ago (Tue)"`. If it's more than a week, I want the regular `"5 days ago"`.

[The docs say](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/) I can supply a function to custom format such a thing:

```
moment.locale('en', {
    relativeTime : {
        future: "in %s",
        past:   "%s ago",
        s:  "seconds",
        m:  "a minute",
        mm: "%d minutes",
        h:  "an hour",
        hh: "%d hours",
        //d:  "a day",   // this is the default
        d:  function(num, noSuffix, key, future) { return "a day (" + FOO + ")"; },
        //dd: "%d days", // this is the default
        dd: function(num, noSuffix, key, future) { return num + "days (" + FOO + ")"; },
        M:  "a month",
        MM: "%d months",
        y:  "a year",
        yy: "%d years"
    }
});
```

The problems are:

- How do I calculate the weekday name for variable `FOO`?
- It returns e.g. `5 days (Mon) ago` instead of `5 days ago (Mon)`
- I want this custom format only if it's <= 7 days (within the last week)

Comment: the day function `dd` returns `"num days (FOO)"` so I suppose you get the `ago` after because you concatenate it after calling the function. If you want it differently you should handle the returned strand in another way.

Answer (score 4):

You can't manipulate the relative time format in the way you asked.  However, you can simply do the comparison yourself to decide whether or not to append the additional string.

```
// your source moment
var m = moment("2015-06-04");

// calculate the number of whole days difference
var d = moment().diff(m,'days');

// create the output string
var s = m.fromNow() + (d >= 1 && d <= 7 ? m.format(" (ddd)") : "");
```